# Efficient way to read a large text file at once java

Tags: java, file, file-read

I want to read a text file that is around 500MB. I have found several methods to read the file line by line. I want to read the file at once without looping line by line. I've tried the following code:

```
String data = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("filepath")));
```

But I am not sure about the efficiency of this line of code. What is the best method to achieve this? I am using Java 8.

Comment: Java heap is a limited resource. Especially in a server environment you don't want to hog 500MB of the heap for a single request. For best stability, process data in smaller batches when possible.

Comment: What do you intend to do with the file contents? The best solution depends entirely on that.

Comment: I am also having same question. I do use this files in Blowfish Encryption.

Comment: As other mentioned, don't load it all in memory. Use memory-mapped file channels (or RandomAccessFile) and operate directly on that. 500MB String is not something java is good at handling.

Comment: You can read millions of lines a second. It isn't a bottleneck. The bottleneck is in what you do with the data. You should process a line at a time, not the entire content at once.

Comment: i want to send this string as response to an api call.

Comment: So you want to send the *file* in response to an API call? There's no need to load the entire thing into memory to accomplish that.